# run python file from another file with dynamic path

Tags: python

I try to run command in my python file, which located in dynamic file. I try to use the `import` statement, which as I understand is the better solution for this case.

Here is the code:

```
from subprocess import call
import tarfile
from contextlib import closing

def tarfile1(path):
    with closing(tarfile.open(path)) as tar:
      tar.extractall(path)
    import path as runcommand
    runcommand.main()
```

The problem is that path is a string, and it gives me the following error:

```
    import path as runcommand
ImportError: No module named path
```

How can I import the file, which I don't know its name, and run the main command from it?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module).

```
import importlib
importlib.import_module(<<mymodule>>)
```

**Note**: Please make sure your module's parent directory is in PYTHONPATH or added in `sys.path`.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
runcommand = __import__(path)
```

instead